# Need to get, analyze and render PDF files in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, npm

I am trying to render a PDF file **from a url**. I then need to analyze the PDF (identify text on it) and then need to show a segment of a page to a user in my React application (segment implies I also need to do some cropping, probably using coordinates and stuff which I get from my analysis).

What npm package(s) do I need to use to accomplish this?

Comment: The rendering can just be done using an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdf-parse and actually parse the text. Cropping PDFs is a rare thing esp. mid-page or so.

PDF parsing will give you a lot of flexibility and you could use other packages atop of that.